# Representing just 'year' and 'year-month' in Clojure/Java

Tags: java, clojure

I am trying to represent *time* information that has precision at the scale of *year* or *year-month*. Eg. 'patient has a history of fracture of the right wrist in **1998**'; 'history of headaches since **October 2015**'.

I looked at [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) which has [YearMonth](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/YearMonth.html) `org.joda.time.YearMonth` but not just 'Year'. But even the YearMonth seems kinda a disconnected. E.g.

```
(clj-time.core/year-month 2015 02)
(clj-time.core/date-time  2015 11 15)

=> #object[org.joda.time.YearMonth 0x7a19d121 "2015-02"]
=> #object[org.joda.time.DateTime 0x5625de93 "2015-11-15T00:00:00.000Z"]
```

and you can do some operations such as:

```
(clj-time.core/month (clj-time.core/year-month 2015 02))
(clj-time.core/month (clj-time.core/date-time  2015 11 15))

=> 2
=> 11
```

but not this:

```
(clj-time.core/before? (clj-time.core/year-month 2015 02)
                       (clj-time.core/date-time  2015 11 15))

=> Exception thrown: java.lang.ClassCastException (org.joda.time.DateTime 
                     cannot be cast to org.joda.time.ReadablePartial)
```

and similar results with `java.time`:

```
(.compareTo (java.time.Year/of 2007) (java.time.LocalDate/now))

=> Exception thrown: java.lang.ClassCastException (java.time.LocalDate
                     cannot be cast to java.time.Year)
```

What I want to be able to do is represent **temporal entities** such as Year and YearMonth at the precision they are - not more, not less, and also do date math with them. E.g.:

- The year **1998** would be represented as an *interval '01 Jan 1998' to '31 Dec 1998'* and **October 2015** as *'01 October 2015' to ' 31 October 2015'*.
- And *be able to compare and do other operations on these **temporal entities***.

Has anyone found a good solution for this? Or should I look at building my own solution/library?

Comment: You write "and be able to compare on these 'dates'", but your examples show that you're also comparing YearMonth and DateTime -- do you need comparison with "normal" time, too or not?

Comment: I was using the word 'dates' above to encompass both intervals such as Year and YearMonth, as well as actual dates. This does extend to what we normally think as a 'date' e.g. '11 December 2015' should be an interval and not '2015-11-21T00:00:00.000' - there is a false sense of precision here.

Comment: @schaueho - I updated the post based on your comment. Changed it from 'dates' to 'temporal entity'. Hope this is clearer.